# database layout issue

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i will try to explain the problem.

I have this structure:

```
offers
--------------
id_offer|offer|company 
1 | web programmer| Microsoft
2 | web programmer| Microsoft


tags
--------------
id_tags | tags
1       | php
2       | js
3       | asp


offers_has_tags
---------------
offers_id_offer (fk) | tags_id_tags (fk)
  1                  | 1
  1                  | 2
  1                  | 3
  2                  | 1
  2                  | 2
```

If i use a system like `Stackoverflow`, where each title of question is unique, there is no problem with the code below. But if i can have various offers with same title, and with same owner, i can't do `WHERE offers = ?`,

So, i need a different approach to select a specific job. Can't be the title, and can't be the owner+title, because the same owner can have various offers with same title.

```
  INSERT INTO `offers_has_tags` (
  offers_id_offer,
  tags_id_tags
  ) 
  VALUES (
  (SELECT id_offer FROM offers WHERE offer = ?), //here
  (SELECT id_tags FROM tags WHERE tags = ?))
```

How can i select an offer when exists more than one, with same title and same owner ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: here ? i am trying be helped..

Comment: There's nothing preventing a StackOverflow question from having the same title as another one.

Comment: I receive an alert message when i use a same title of another previous question by other user: _a question with that title already exists; please be more specific._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: there is no way to retrieve exactly one row from table if your where clause is not filtering rows by PK columns.

It is not 100% clear what You are trying to achieve. However, **primary key is used to uniquely identify the row**. This means that in this case You should use offer_id in where clause (in your insert statement in original question).

I guess that you have some UI in front of this - why don't your UI send offer_id to data access code instead of offer name?

But, if You want to insert all offers with same name and owner to offer_has_tag, try this (it is T-SQL syntax but as far as I can recall it should work on MySQL also):

```
INSERT INTO `offers_has_tags` (
  offers_id_offer,
  tags_id_tags
  ) 
SELECT id_offer, (SELECT id_tags FROM tags WHERE tags = ?)
FROM offers WHERE offer = ? AND company = ?)
```

Please note that You should use id_tags instead of tag name in your queries. Only use descriptive attributes in filtering the list for end user. Otherwise, use primary key columns.

Comment: @Daniel, I just read those comments and I am sorry but no one will be able to help You, because of the sentence in bold in my answer. There is just no way to get only one row if the value You filter for is not unique (and to be sure it is unique, columns you use in where clause must be in PK or unique index). Or I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, it is the problem. the title can't be unique, so how can I filter the offer? maybe time stamp ?

Comment: If one owner can't post more offers with the same name then put unique index on offer field. Otherwise, maybe You want to enforce business rule that only one offer from one owner can be placed in one period of time (additional columns ValidFrom, ValidTo) then You can use those filters for additional filtering. But, If You add timestamp column only, then You will have basically the same: either you have to know id_offer or timestamp. Or you just want to take the latter one? Then You can take advantage of timestamp.

Comment: yes, probably makes sense delete the id_offer and only use timestamp as PK. With timestamp and title, i can select a specific offer (even with same title ) . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a bit more specific? In which situation are you executing the sql, for which purpose and in which way are the arguments given? Maybe post the code that's in front of these statements.
That could helping answer your question. The thing I'm wondering at the moment, why is it a problem to get more than one case as result?

Comment: to clarify. Two offers with same title, with same owner can be tagged with different keywords. In my example (sql code) if i do `WHERE offer = "web programmer"`, i will get two results, so i will tag two offers with same tags. do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: Not really. I asked some more questions that are still not answered; kind of hard to figure out what the purpose of all this is. Only thing I imagine now is that you've got a website, and you want to show all the job offers whit a specific title and specific tags or something?

Comment: No. Basically at this stage, the only thing that i want is tagging the offers. the user write the title of offer and assign the tags. The problem is exclusively about select an unique offer that can have the same owner and the same title. how can I select it in subquery?

Comment: This substitutes to the answer of Filip; your talking about selecting an unique offer. That means that offer needs to have an unique attribute, like id (e.g. key) and that your searching in your SQL query for that unique ID. id_offer and id_tags should be unique key values, and you could search for a specific id. That would return one row.

Comment: but, to select the id, that will be unique, i need another attribute to search. The only thing that i remember is title + timestamp. Do you suggest any different approach ?

Comment: how come that when you search, you don't know the id your searching for, but do know the timestamp? 
I would try to make the ID unique. If it is that your using the id now to group or categorize, just create a new field with a category. Which on intselfs maybe overdone, because you already have the tags